# Why I have this error in my trigger? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I am creating a MySQL database, I want to create a trigger to change the amount of inventory available after a sale, but I get an error

This is the code of the trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_inventario;
CREATE TRIGGER tr_inventario AFTER INSERT ON factura FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE producto INNER JOIN factura ON producto.IdProducto=factura.IdProducto
    SET producto.Invenatario=producto.Invenatario-factura.Cantidad 
    WHERE producto.IdProducto=factura.IdProducto;
```

This is the INSERT that i want to do

```
INSERT INTO factura(FechaVenta, NombreCliente, IdProducto, IdEmpleado, Cantidad) VALUES (now(), 'María Guadalupe',3, 2, 2);
```

And this is the error that I get

```
Error Code: 1048. Column 'Invenatario' cannot be null
```

[relational table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edita.png)

Comment: show us your `producto` table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `JOIN`:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_inventario AFTER INSERT ON factura FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE producto p
        SET p.Invenatario = p.Invenatario - new.Cantidad 
    WHERE p.IdProducto = new.IdProducto;
END;
```

Comment: oh, thank you very much indeed.
I don't have much experience in this